# Protractor in headless chrome doesn't execute browser.actions()

Tags: angular, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

My protractor.conf.js(relevant parts)

```
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      'args': ['headless', 'disable-gpu']
    }
  }
```

If I run protractor in normal mode all tests passing. As well as if i replace this piece of code with just map.click().

```
  browser.actions()
  .mouseDown()
  .mouseMove(map, {x: 500, y: 150})
  .click()
  .mouseDown()
  .perform();
```

Edit: I did not add errors before because I thought they are no use in my situation. But here they are since someone thinks they are relevant.

Failures:

> 1) Protractor Demo App place sorting should create 2 places on
>   different distances from map center   Message:
>       Expected 0 to be 2.   Stack:
>       Error: Failed expectation
>           at Object.it (/home/piliponful/projects/mocha-test/spec.js:138:38)
>           at /home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:112:25
>           at new ManagedPromise (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1067:7)
>           at ControlFlow.promise (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2396:12)
>           at schedulerExecute (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:95:18)
>           at TaskQueue.execute_ (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2970:14)
>           at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2953:27)
>           at asyncRun (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2860:25)
>           at /home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:676:7
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
>
> 2) Protractor Demo App place sorting should sort places   Message:
>       Expected 0 to be 2.   Stack:
>       Error: Failed expectation
>           at Object.it (/home/piliponful/projects/mocha-test/spec.js:148:38)
>           at /home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:112:25
>           at new ManagedPromise (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1067:7)
>           at ControlFlow.promise (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2396:12)
>           at schedulerExecute (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:95:18)
>           at TaskQueue.execute_ (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2970:14)
>           at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2953:27)
>           at asyncRun (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2860:25)
>           at /home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:676:7
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)   Message:
>       Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator
>   by.binding("place.title")   Stack:
>       NoSuchElementError: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator
>   by.binding("place.title")
>           at selenium_webdriver_1.promise.all.then (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:287:17)
>           at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1366:14)
>           at TaskQueue.execute_ (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2970:14)
>           at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2953:27)
>           at asyncRun (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2813:27)
>           at /home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:676:7
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)Error
>           at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:482:23)
>           at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function).args [as getText] (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:96:21)
>           at ElementFinder.(anonymous function).args [as getText] (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:873:14)
>           at placeListText.then.places (/home/piliponful/projects/mocha-test/spec.js:150:38)
>           at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1366:14)
>           at TaskQueue.execute_ (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2970:14)
>           at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2953:27)
>           at asyncRun (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2813:27)
>           at /home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:676:7
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
>       From: Task: Run it("should sort places") in control flow
>           at Object. (/home/piliponful/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:94:19)
>           at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
>           at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
>           at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
>       From asynchronous test: 
>       Error
>           at Suite.describe (/home/piliponful/projects/mocha-test/spec.js:140:5)
>           at Suite.describe (/home/piliponful/projects/mocha-test/spec.js:87:3)
>           at Object. (/home/piliponful/projects/mocha-test/spec.js:1:1)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
>           at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
>           at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
>           at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
>           at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
>
> 13 specs, 3 failures

Comment: Your questions seems to be half? What error are you getting?

Comment: I added errors.

Comment: I would check to see if chrome-headless supports these features in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found a solution to get protractor browser.actions() to work with  headless mode in chrome. But I used Xvfb docker image(webnicer/protractor-headless) and it all worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your options syntax is different from [Protractor specifications](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md#using-headless-chrome). Also, headless needs you specify window-size upfront. Please try this and see if it helps.

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      'args': ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=800,600']
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can't use `mouseMove()` in headless chrome as not all browser actions will work as expected.  For example, `browser.actions().sendKeys(Key.DELETE).perform()`

Instead of mouseMove(), just use:

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", map)

map.click()
```